# Как записать все данные в базу, а так же потом их вывести?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется таблица, с очень большим количеством данных. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как эти все данные собрать и записать в базу, а потом вывести. Так же, не знаю, как правильно базу разметить. Поэтому прошу подсказать с решением этого вопроса.

Таблица сама выглядит вот таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это одна строка, при клике на "+", добавляется новая строчка данных, например, если нажать на "+" в первой яйчейке, то получим вот такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В такой ситуации ничего сложного, но каждый последующий "+" добавляет новую подстрочку данных, увеличивая количество записей. Если продолжить добавлять поля, то это будет выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это получается всего лишь две строки, но с большим количеством параллельных записей. Реализована таблица, если это поможет делу, через создание таблицы внутри таблицы.

Как под такой массив данных спроектировать базу и как лучше собирать массив для записи, а так же, для вывода данных в эту таблицу - не знаю. Прошу совета по этой теме.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил)

Comment: Что за таблицу используете?

Comment: Если речь о базе данных, то это mysql, тип myisam.

Comment: Что за интерфейс такой? штатно MySQL такого не предоставляет. Какая-то самописка?

Comment: а, вот о чём речь, это просто свёрстанный интерфейс, откуда данные будут браться и куда потом будут выводиться

Answer (score 0):

Для переноса данных можете воспользоваться [миграциями](https://webdevkin.ru/posts/backend/mysql-migrations), или же сделать dump БД.

Название полей можно придумать по логике, к примеру поле со странами `country`, поле с названием товара `item`, поле с фамилией работника `worker_surname`. Всю логику и все связи можно настроить при создании таблицы, накатить данные не так проблематично, как создать хорошую структуру и "проложить" все связи.